# Placing blocks on specific blocks only

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have one question. I have been creating some maps lately and I want to have a lever only place able on white wool. though I am always watching and reading tutorials on how to, but they don't seem to have it for 1.13, I really need this for 1.13 please help.

Comment: It's basically the same for 1.13. Did you even try it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! A good introduction to our site [can be found here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Fabian Röling yes I did try it, it keeps pooping up red and not working

Comment: @user225445 Then tell us the error message. Would you be able to repair a sink based on "the water is strange"?

Comment: ah I see it, it wont give it to me because there is not space between "lever" and "CanPlaceOn", but there is still a problem. whenever I put my mouse over the item it does not say "can be placed on white wool" it says "can be placed on missingo". :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what command you've been using, but this definitely works:

```
/give @s lever{CanPlaceOn:["white_wool"]}
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening, but nothing works. including this :(

Comment: Did you put it in a command block? If it's in a command block it won't work because @s targets the self, so the command block doesn't know what self to give it to. Just use @p, @a or @r instead. Does it work now?

Comment: No, I did put it in a command block, and changed @p to @a.

Comment: @user225445 This is strange, it sounds like if you did everything correctly it should be working. Did you remove the slash first? There might be a very slight chance that that could be the problem, idk. Does it work with console command, when you press "/" and copy and paste it in there?